# How to investigate class imbalance in multiple csv file on python?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to investigate the class imbalance in a set of 10 csv file.

To achieve that, I am trying to concat all the y_train (let's ignore y_test) from all the 10 files in one long vertical column so that I can use `y_train.value_count()`.

The problem is that, when I try to concat these files an error appears.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

datasets = ['CHEMBL4794', 'CHEMBL4805', 'CHEMBL4822', 'CHEMBL1293228', 'CHEMBL1741171',
            'CHEMBL1907607', 'CHEMBL1907608', 'CHEMBL1907610', 'CHEMBL2093869', 
            'CHEMBL2094108']

all_y_train = []

def run_check(dataset): 
    df_train = pd.read_csv(f'C:\\Users\\AMahmud\\Classification_Analysis\\input\\base_processed\\{dataset}_train.csv')

    x_train = df_train.drop(columns = ['molecule_id','pXC50'])
    y_train = (df_train.pXC50)
    all_y_train = pd.concat(y_train)
    
    
def check_balance():
    for dataset in datasets:
        run_check(dataset)
        
check_balance()
```

Error:

```
first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "Series"
```

How can resolve the error? On top of that, how to investigate the class imbalance more efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it your way, you would need to specify that

- `all_y_train` is an empty Series: `all_y_train = pd.Series()`
- `pd.concat` takes a list of arguments: `pd.concat([all_y_train, y_train])`
- `check_balance()` takes `datasets` as argument: `def check_balance(datasets):` (though your code works without this modification in a Jupyter Notebook)

However, the easier way to do what you want is to concatenate your csv files like this:

`all_csvs = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f'C:\\Users\\AMahmud\\Classification_Analysis\\input\\base_processed\\{dataset}_train.csv') for dataset in datasets])`

Comment: Much appreciated max_Jump.
Your alternative solution looks interesting. A reason why I might be hesitant to take that route is the scalability. If I am working with 2000+ datasets, combining all the csv files will increase the computational time, na?